# Examining position intersect and conditionally drop row based on P-values

Tags: r, conditional-statements, bioinformatics, gwas

I'm working my way through post-analysis of GWAS, where I have defined a list of independent SNPs associated with my trait.
I'm trying to group my indep. SNPs in loci of +- 500KB. There are some independent SNP's which locus will overlap each other and I'm trying to write a code that will drop the SNP with the higher P-value, if the two loci overlap.

```
   SNP       bp            p
1: rs1  8537289  1.33785e-08
2: rs2  12263919 5.03939e-11
3: rs3  19771438 1.83669e-20
4: rs4  19845279 3.60144e-18
```

Afterward adding two columns with position +- 500kb, where it becomes evident, that row 3 and 4 have overlapping genomic positions.

```
   SNP       bp           p    start     stop
1: rs1  8537289 1.33785e-08  8037289  9037289
2: rs2 12263919 5.03939e-11 11763919 12763919
3: rs3 19771438 1.83669e-20 19271438 20271438
4: rs4 19845279 3.60144e-18 19345279 20345279
```

What I am trying to do from here, is work my way in to a conditional code, that will keep the SNP with the lowest P-value (in this example rs3), and then drop the fourth row containing rs4.

So that i will get the following result:

```
  SNP       bp           p    start     stop
1: rs1  8537289 1.33785e-08  8037289  9037289
2: rs2 12263919 5.03939e-11 11763919 12763919
3: rs3 19771438 1.83669e-20 19271438 20271438
```

I'm well aware that plink clumping is the usual procedure for defining loci, but I'm trying this as an alternative and robust way to establish associations to the trait. I hope someone is willing to share a piece of their brilliant skill and I promise the best of good karma in return. Cheers

**EDIT**

Looking through the results, I noticed an unintentional fault produced with the great solution provided by @Axeman. My apologies if I didn't express myself properly.
I ran the following code to print the "g-column" without dropping SNPs

```
d1 <- d %>% group_by(Chr,p, locus = cumsum(minus > lag(plus, default=1)))
%>% slice_min(p)
```

And noticed when the chromosome changes from n to n2, the non-overlapping genomic region is merged into one locus. So that the last locus at chromosome n and the first locus at n2 is "merged" (or dropped). Would you know how to work your way around it?

Comment: RE edit: Something like `d %>% group_by(Chr) %>% mutate(locus = cumsum(minus > lag(plus, default=1))) %>% group_by(Chr, locus) %>% slice_min(p)`?

Comment: That solved it. Appreciate the help, wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define groups for overlapping sections, then filter for the lowest p-value. E.g.:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(g = cumsum(start > lag(stop, default = 1))) %>% 
  slice_min(p)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 6
> # Groups:   g [3]
>   SNP         bp        p    start     stop     g
>   <chr>    <int>    <dbl>    <int>    <int> <int>
> 1 rs1    8537289 1.34e- 8  8037289  9037289     1
> 2 rs2   12263919 5.04e-11 11763919 12763919     2
> 3 rs3   19771438 1.84e-20 19271438 20271438     3
> ```

This is greedy in the sense that it will group together SNPs that are not overlapping if there is a SNP between them that overlaps with both. Not sure what you want to do in the case of sequences of partially overlapping SNPs.